# how to work with JSON code from OpenWeatherMap.org API in HTML

Tags: html, json, api

I am relatively new to programming and I am making a HTML website where I want to show weather data. I have got an API from openweathermap.org.
When I type the API in google I get data in JSON code.

```
{"coord":{"lon":5.46,"lat":51.35},
"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],
"base":"stations","main":
{"temp":5.72,"feels_like":1.32,"temp_min":5.56,"temp_max":6.11,
"pressure":998,"humidity":70},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":3.6,"deg":160},
"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1607178963,"sys":
{"type":1,"id":1527,"country":"NL","sunrise":1607153201,"sunset":1607182290},
"timezone":3600,"id":2745860,"name":"Valkenswaard","cod":200}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get the data into my HTML website.
I would like to know how to get JSON code into a HTML website.

Comment: Are you familiar with javascript or JQuery? You'll need to be familiar with one of them to do this. The API gives you data, but you're going to need to use javascript to turn that data into HTML.

Comment: You're going to need a lot of javascript. The way it works is this:

1. Get the data from the URL using `ajax`.

2. The data you get is... probably going to be returned in an array. You need to loop over the array with a `foreach` to go over each element in your array.

3. For each element, you're going to need to get the items, and print them as HTML inside, say, a `<p>` or `<div>` element.